# Prove $f$ separable iff $g$ separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Let $L|K$ be the splitting field of $f$ and $g$, which they are irreducible polynomials.

Prove that  $f$ is separable if and only $g$ is separable.

How can I prove it? I've tried lots of things but they didn't conlude anything. If you could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: First, show a "tower result": if $M/L/K$ is a tower of algebraic extensions, $M/K$ is separable iff $M/L$ and $L/K$ are. Second, show that if $x$ is algebraic over $K'$ that is separable over $K$, and $x$ is separable over $K$, then $K'[x]$ separable over $K$. Conclude from this that if $f$ is separable, then every element of $L$ is separable over $K$, and in particular $g$ is the minimal polynomial of a separable element thus is separable.

Comment: I don't understand; $L$ is the splitting field of $f\in K[x]$ ? What is $g$ ?

Comment: $L$ is the splitting field of both $f$ and $g$ over K, furthermore they are irreducible.